# Simplify Julia tuple creation

Tags: julia

i need to convert

```
2-element Vector{Matrix{Tuple{Real, Real}}}:
 [(1, 2) (1.8, 2.1) (3, 2)]
 [(1, 3) (2.2, 2.9) (3, 3)]
```

into

```
(Vector{Real}[[1, 1.8, 3], [1, 2.2, 3]], Vector{Real}[[2, 2.1, 2], [3, 2.9, 3]])
```

For that my naive approach is

```
a=[[(1,2) (1.8,2.1) (3,2)],[(1,3) (2.2,2.9) (3,3)]]
b=([first.(s)|>vec for s in a],[last.(s)|>vec for s in a])
```

1. Is there a way to write expressions like this simpler (i.e. without repeating most of the `[somefunc.(s)|>vec for s in a]` expression)?
2. Is this an efficient solution for `a` containing >1e6 elements in both vectors?

Comment: just wondering what's the context here? this much type instability suggests you are doing something rather odd.

Comment: @OscarSmith I have a Vector of Vectors containing (x,y) tuples. I want to plot them with Plots.jl and i've found out that a tuple containing vectors with the x and y coordinates works with the `plot()` function.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but having the internal vectors of tuples as columns instead of rows speeds up your approach.

Comment: If you are using this for plotting, why are you working with `Real`s instead of `Float64` or `Float32`? This will probably have negative consequences for performance.

Comment: @DNF This wasn't intentional. When i've created the vector with `a=[[(1,2) (1.8,2.1) (3,2)],[(1,3) (2.2,2.9) (3,3)]]` it automatically got `Real`. Should i specify `Float32`?

Comment: I would just write `[(1.0, 2.0), (1.8, 2.1), (3.0, 2.0)]` etc. No particular need for Float32, unless you're on a GPU, I think.

Answer (score 2):

To get the first element in the tuple you want a way could be

```
map(i -> reshape(getindex.(i, 1), :), v)
```

So then

```
Tuple(map(i -> reshape(getindex.(i,j),:), v) for j in 1:2)
```

Should give you the output you want, I am not sure this is too much nicer.

Performance is the same but I can run it within a second for 1.e6 in my laptop so it should be okay unless you have really large vectors.

EDIT: I had written 8 in place of 6